# How to calculate two location distance?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

calculate two locations distance if distance is greater than 5 Kms you have to return true?

Plz help me,i am new to MapView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

 CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1];

 CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:long2];

 CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];

 //Distance in Meters

if((distance*1000)>5)
{
    //return true;
    // your coding
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have coordinates of the points.

```
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1];

 CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:long2];

 CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
```

Also you need to `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` as mentioned by Dharmesh Dhorajiya